# Pre-heat CoreML MLModel

Tags: ios, swift, coreml, mlmodel

I'm seeing up to 3x-4x slower results on my first prediction on my `MLModel`. Seems like once you run the first prediction it's heating the model. Couldn't find any official information about it.

What is the right way to pre-heat my model? Call it on an async thread on app launch with dummy data?

Comment: It seems that it is lazy loading the model (implicitly) upon the first request. iOS 14+ includes an explicit async [loading function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mlmodel/3600218-load) that notifies you via a callback when loading finishes, so if you target pre iOS 14 your workaround sounds like a valid choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Alladinian mentioned, starting from iOS 14 you can use the `MLModel.load(contentsOf:...)` function.
Here is a usage example for pre-loading a local `.mlmodel` file:

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myModel", withExtension: "mlmodelc") {
    let config = MLModelConfiguration()
    MLModel.load(contentsOf: url, configuration: config) { [weak self] result in
        switch result {
            case .success(let model):
                print("Model loaded and ready.")
                let modelWrapper = MyModelWrapper(model: model)
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error loading model: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to pre-load an externally fetched model, make sure it's compiled using `MLModel.compileModel(at:)`.